# How to get the error value in tensorflow for Neural Network

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I have been trying the below code to implement neural network, But I m facing challenge in displaying the loss value. Could some one help me?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data", one_hot=True)

x_input = mnist.train.images[:100,:]
y_input = mnist.train.labels[:100,:]


LearningRate = 0.01
noOfEpocs = 10

#N/w params
hidden_1_Neurons = 50
hidden_2_Neurons = 50
inputNeurons = 784
noOfClasses = 10

X  = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, inputNeurons])
Y =  tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])

#Let's Fill Data

hidden_1_weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([inputNeurons, hidden_1_Neurons]))
hidden_2_weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden_1_Neurons, hidden_2_Neurons]))
outLayer_weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden_2_Neurons, noOfClasses]))

hidden_1_Bias = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden_1_Neurons]))
hidden_2_Bias = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hidden_2_Neurons]))
outLayer_Bias = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([noOfClasses]))


hidden_1 =  tf.add(tf.matmul(X ,hidden_1_weights), hidden_1_Bias)
hidden_2 =  tf.add (tf.matmul(hidden_1, hidden_2_weights), hidden_2_Bias)
outLayer  =  tf.add (tf.matmul(hidden_2, outLayer_weights), outLayer_Bias)

softMaxOutput = tf.nn.softmax(outLayer)

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(Y * tf.log(softMaxOutput),reduction_indices=[1]))
training = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cross_entropy)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

sess.run(training, feed_dict={X:x_input, Y:y_input})
actualLoss = sess.run(cross_entropy, feed_dict={X:x_input, Y:y_input})
print ("actualLoss ", actualLoss)
```

I m getting the output like:

```
#actualLoss  nan
```

I presume it says nan(Not a Number). Is this coding is right to get the actual loss?

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the `softmaxOutput` variable and use tf builtin `softmax_cross_entropy` loss function, it does apply softmax activation and handle the cross entropy loss.

```
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=outLayer, labels=Y))
```

but regarding your problem it was due to `log(softmaxOutput)` if the output is zeros it will cause it to output nan so you have to add a very small value to it to overcome the problem `1e-5`

```
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(Y * tf.log(softMaxOutput + 1e-5),reduction_indices=[1]))`
```

Comment: It is not absolutely clear that this is the solution, but it is true that cross-entropy has known issues with numerical stability, which might be causing this problem.  https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/Paddle/issues/1181

Comment: Also, there is no need to remove the `softmaxOutput` layer, unless you don't intend to use the trained model, or you intend to load the weights into a 'prediction' model in order to save a few kb of memory by not defining layers until the absolute second you need them.

Comment: @Scott It's not necessary but its the way in the official tensorflow docs to only apply the softmax at prediction time so I pointed it out